# Problems with Ubuntu 14.04 and Realtek Wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, realtek

I have a Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 and wifi network adapter Realtek RTL8723BE. My wifi works fine for some time, but after a somewhat random amount of minutes (between 15 and 30), it looses all connection and the only way of regaining the connection is to restart the computer.

One suggestion I've read on a forum is to update the kernel from 3.13 to 3.16. I did that but to no avail, everything was still the same. After some 20 minutes, no wifi.

I will really appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a common issue, solved some of the time by entering the following in terminal and rebooting `echo "options rtl8723be swenc=Y ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`